# Два ScrollView на одном экране

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, scrollview

Подскажите, мне нужно сделать ScrollView внутри ScrollView так, чтобы первый скролился только вертикально, а второй только горизонтально по подобию того как в приложении вконтакте фотографии скроллятся. Первый вертикально скролится, а второй заставить не могу.

Comment: А Вы сделали ограничение в первом только на вертикальный скролл, а во втором только на горизонтальный? Все должно работать без проблем.

Comment: @Mihael какое ограничение? в свойствах ScrollView есть только возможность отключить отображение горизонтальной или вертикальной полосы прокрутки.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, перепутал с UICollectionView. А DirectionLock пробовали включать?

Comment: что то не получается вашу проблему воспроизвести - сделал два скролл вью, один в другом. поставил контент сайз чтоб один не помещался в свой фрейм по горизонтали, второй по вертикали - все работает.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko у вас autolayout включен при этом?